# How to reset counter in prometheus push gateway

Tags: python, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I Want to reset the counter to 0 in prometheus push gateway because  prometheus push gateway will keep on sending last counter value to prometheus. i don't that to be happen in my condition.

Comment: I think you need to explain more how you are trying to set this value to 0, because according to [docs of writing libraries](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_clientlibs/#counter), setting value of Counter to 0 is happening in cases like restarting server and as the doc says, clients must implement **inc()** and **inc(double v)**.

Comment: i reframed  question can you look at into this

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, your question is that you push some metric (a counter) but you don't want this metric to stay forever in the push gateway. The bottom line is that there is no timeout on metrics in push gateway and there won't be in the [foreseeable future](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/issues/19).

If possible, you can schedule a [DELETE request](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#delete-method) in order to remove the metric (rather than reset it) after the time you want. A popular method is also to use a [textfile tied to a node exporter](https://www.robustperception.io/using-the-textfile-collector-from-a-shell-script) which will disappear with your node. It depends on your environment and setup.

Answer (score 0):

According to Prometheus docs ([Counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) and [Gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge)), I guess Gauge fits better into your problem, because according to this doc of [prometheus_client counter](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#counter) for python,

> Counters go up and reset when the process restarts.

So it's unlikely that you can set 0 value for Counter.

But [Gauges](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#gauge) can go up and down and set a certain value like 0.

Comment: IMHO the original problem is more related to the usage of the push gateway.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez I guess you are right and I liked your answer, but still I think there is ambiguity in question.

Comment: Agreed, a pushgateway hints at a batch job and, in this case, counters don't really make sense. If it is really a counter, it means the pushgateway is likely not the right tool.